# How can I replace duplicate elements with its first occurrence index in Numpy? (first occurrence indices)

Tags: python, numpy

for exmaple,
I have two arrays: 'x' for actual values, 'I' for their index in array.

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4]
I = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

in 'x',
the 4th value is duplicate one of 3rd value
and the 5th value is duplicate one of 2nd value

Therefore, I want to generate the

```
y = [0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 5]
```

(containing first occurrence indicies of original array values)

How can I do this efficiently using python numpy methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
u, idx, inv = np.unique(x, return_inverse=True, return_index=True)
>>> idx
array([0, 1, 2, 5], dtype=int64)
>>> inv
array([0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3], dtype=int64)
>>> idx[inv]
array([0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 5], dtype=int64)
```

No, after it's clear, read the docs of [`np.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html):

- `inv` are the indices of the unique array that can be used to reconstruct `x`.
- `idx` are the indices of `x` that result in the unique array.

So you just take the indices of `x` that result in the unique array and reconstruct them instead of `x`